# Can I currently purchase a perpetual game maker studio 2 mobile development license on steam and then transfer it to my yoyogames account?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I am considering purchasing a license to create mobile games with game maker studio 2.  They have recently updated from a perpetual license model to a subscription model.  However, it appears that it is still possible to buy a perpetual license if it is purchased through steam.  I know that it is possible to link a steam account to a yoyo games account.  But, is it possible to get a perpetual license for mobile development on steam, and then transfer it to my yoyo games account so that I can develop for mobile without using the steam version of gms2?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with Steam licences, it might be an oversight on the Yoyogames side. Though you may consider if it really benefits your need. €80 for permanent use vs €9 at the moment of export. It does allow some flexibility though, as you don't have to stress for post release updates.

Comment: @Steven Yes, this makes sense.  And actually, what I was thinking of trying the monthly subscription for a month or two, and then if I feel it is worth buying, buying for a longer period.  But the full year subscription is $100, so if I could transfer the steam perpetual license to my yoyo account, I think that would be most ideal.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Gamemaker Studio 2 for developing for any platform has become free, and you only need to pay for the export, so I'm no sure what you want to try out with the monthly subscription. Though I do agree that it's absurd that staying subscribed for a whole year is just as expensive as owning a permanent license.

Comment: @Steven I didn't realize you could test on android/ios without paying...

Comment: @Steven Alright I see... good to know.  So you are unsure if a steam license can be "transferred" to yoyogames account?

Comment: Mostly because I havn't tried it myself, I think it is possible after hearing other people on different websites. But I have no confirmation on that. I also don't want to try out, because Yoyogames could (I repeat: "could") take legal actions to remove your license for avoiding their subscriptions.

Comment: Dear Steven, please at least search for an announcement or FAQ before hypothesizing about legal actions.

Comment: @Steven hmm interesting... can you recall where you saw them say that they could take legal action to remove the license?

Comment: I'm retracting my previous comment, as I said that without knowing an example. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Steven That's alright, no worries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link a Steam account to YoYo Games account [on the dashboard](https://accounts.yoyogames.com/linked_accounts) to have access to those licences without having to run GameMaker via Steam;

As per [FAQ](https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405059050001-Subscriptions-FAQ), if you buy a permanent licence, you keep it, including the current Steam licences (which have not been updated to subscription model yet).